# Spring Boot JSON Serialization of Nulls

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, jackson

How do I force null objects to be serialized as an empty string in my default JSON responses in Spring Boot?

I would like it to show as:

```
{
    myProperty: "",
}
```

But what comes out by default is:

```
{
    myProperty: null,
}
```

I don't want myProperty to be excluded from this list, so I'm not interested in changing the `JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL`

Here is what I've tried:

In my main `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` class:

```
@Autowired
private NullAsEmptyStringSerializer nullSerializer;

@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer addCustomSerialization() {
    return jacksonObjectMapperBuilder -> {
        DefaultSerializerProvider serializerProvider = new DefaultSerializerProvider.Impl();
        serializerProvider.setNullValueSerializer(nullSerializer);
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setSerializerProvider(serializerProvider);
        jacksonObjectMapperBuilder.configure(objectMapper);
    };
```

And then my `nullSerializer` object class:

```
@Component
public class NullAsEmptyStringSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Object o, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        jsonGenerator.writeString("\"\"");
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `serialize()` method is never called on my custom class.

Comment: `{myProperty: }` is not valid JSON; there's no way you'll coerce Jackson to produce invalid JSON. You'll have to post-process the output as a String. Consider if creating invalid JSON is the right way to go.

Comment: @Bohemian edited to make you happy. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with this configuration through `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` lies in these lines:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
jacksonObjectMapperBuilder.configure(objectMapper);
```

In fact, this has no effect, because the builder always uses its own instance of `ObjectMapper`, created internally. If we check in the source code of the builder:

```
public <T extends ObjectMapper> T build() {
  ObjectMapper mapper;
  // conditional instantiation of mapper
  configure(mapper);
  return (T) mapper;
}
```

Our previous instance of `ObjectMapper` is just ignored.

Unfortunately, there is no way to set `SerializerProvider`s through `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`. Probably, this feature is not yet implemented in the API.

But there are at least two possible solutions for the problem.

*First*, according to the [official Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper), you can always create your own `ObjectMapper` bean marked with `@Primary` and configured fully as you wish, for example:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
  DefaultSerializerProvider serializerProvider = new DefaultSerializerProvider.Impl();
  serializerProvider.setNullValueSerializer(nullSerializer);
  ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
  objectMapper.setSerializerProvider(serializerProvider);
  return objectMapper;
}
```

This will enable the `nullSerializer` properly, but the drawback is that Spring's auto-configuration of the `ObjectMapper` instance will be lost and that is probably not what you always want.

*The second solution* goes through bootstrapping the default instance of `ObjectMapper` and setting the desired property on it. This can be achieved by implementing the `InitializingBean` interface, in quite an easy way:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class ObjectMapperConfig implements InitializingBean {

  @Autowired
  private NullAsEmptyStringSerializer nullSerializer;

  @Autowired
  private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

  // will be called by Spring after all the beans are created
  // and the proper `objectMapper` instance is available here.
  @Override
  public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    DefaultSerializerProvider serializerProvider = new DefaultSerializerProvider.Impl();
    serializerProvider.setNullValueSerializer(nullSerializer);
    objectMapper.setSerializerProvider(serializerProvider);
  }

}
```

Last but not least, there is a small problem in the `NullAsEmptyStringSerializer` above.

```
jsonGenerator.writeString("\"\"");
```

will output `"myProperty":"\"\""`. This should be changed to

```
jsonGenerator.writeString("");
```